# C++20 modules export template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-modules

I'm creating a library and I have a class template inside a C++20 module and I want to add an instantiation in order to reduce compilation time for every project that uses my library.

Are these different implementations equivalent, or is there a better way to achieve it?

1)

```
//mod.cpp
export module mod;

export template<typename T>
struct mystruct{ T i;};

export template class mystruct<int>;
```

2. 

```
//mod.cpp
export module mod;

export template<typename T>
struct mystruct{ T i;};

template class mystruct<int>;
```

3. 

```
//mod.cpp
export module mod;

export template<typename T>
struct mystruct{ T i;};

export extern template class mystruct<int>;



//mod_impl.cpp
module mod;

template class mystruct<int>;
```

**Edit**: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61520847/how-to-use-template-explicit-instantiation-with-c20-modules) says only that 2. works, but my point is  if also 1. and 3. are equivalent to 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use template explicit instantiation with C++20 modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61520847/how-to-use-template-explicit-instantiation-with-c20-modules)

Comment: @Genjutsu that is exactly case 2., but I want to know if 1. and 3. bring to the same result or instead are different.

Comment: @desio: So basically, you have two questions: 1) is `export`ing an explicit instantiation in the module interface important for exposing the explicit instantiation to users of the module? 2) if I `extern` it in the interface and instantiate it in the implementation, does that work just as well?

Comment: @NicolBolas yes, and 3) if I don't export a template instantiation it'll be visible outside anyway or not?

Comment: @desio: That's just a restatement of 1.

Comment: Oh yes exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules affect 2 things: the scope of names and the reach-ability of declarations. Both of these only matter if they are within the purview of a module (ie: in an imported module interface TU and not being in the global module fragment).

Names declared in the purview of a module can be used outside of that module only if they are `export`ed by that module. In the case of an explicit template instantiation, the template *itself* is already exported, so users outside of the module can already use the name.

However, an explicit template instantiation definition is also a declaration. And modules control the reach-ability of declarations. The thing is, [the rules of reach-ability for a declaration](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/module.reach#3) don't actually *care* about `export`:

> A declaration D is reachable if, for any point P in the instantiation context ([module.context]),
>
> - D appears prior to P in the same translation unit, or
> - D is not discarded ([module.global.frag]), appears in a translation unit that is reachable from P, and does not appear within a private-module-fragment.
>
> [ Note: Whether a declaration is exported **has no bearing** on whether it is reachable. — end note ]

Emphasis added.

These rules only care about which TUs have been imported (and whether the declaration is in a global/private module fragment).

Therefore, if the primary template declaration was `export`ed, an explicit template instantiation (that is *not* in the global/private module fragment) in one of the imported module files is reach-able by any code that imports it.

So it doesn't matter if you `export` an explicit template instantiation. If the primary template was already `export`ed, its name could already be used, so the only thing that matters is if the explicit template instantiation is visible.

So your #1 and 2 are functionally equivalent. And its best not to `export` something you don't need to.

---

As for the behavior of `extern template`, that's interesting.

While `extern` normalize denotes external linkage, this does not apply to `extern template`. So we don't have linkage problems. And since the `extern template` declaration is reach-able by importers of the module (as previously stated), they'll see it and respect it.

So the only question is whether the explicit *definition* in your "mod_impl.cpp" is also reach-able. Except that's not a question because only the *declaration* part of a definition is ever "reach-able". That is, reach-ability only matters for a declaration.

The explicit instantiation definition is in a different TU. Therefore, it will only be instantiated in that TU; code which imports the module reaches only the declaration. And therefore, it won't instantiate the template.

So yes, you can perform `extern template` gymnastics (though again, `export` doesn't matter). But it's no different than just putting the explicit instantiation in your module interface, and it's way cleaner to do that.

Comment: For those who may have forgotten: [What is a C++ module purview?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49204175/1593077)

Comment: @einpoklum: Your answer could use some updating to include the global and private module fragments, which are not part of a C++20's module purview. And also the `module;` construct that is required to start the global module fragment.

Comment: Mentioned the global module fragment in footnote to the answer. But it doesn't matter all that much, I think.