# Templates Exports in Modules C++

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++20, c++-modules

I have a templated class in a module file and when exporting the module it works fine, however when importaing I get a COMDAT exception. Are there specific constraints on how to export templated classes out of modules. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70643026/c20-modules-export-template-instantiation), however it seems not to solve the COMDAT exception I receive. My code has the following Layout:

```cpp
export namespace Foo {
    template <typename T>
    class Bar {
      ...
    }
}
```

However, when I link it with my GoogleTest Project and compile that one I receive a:

```
LNK1179 invalid or corrupt file: duplicate COMDAT '??$_Allocate_manually_vector_aligned@U_Default_allocate_traits@std@@@std@@YAPEAX_K@Z' ...
```

Finally, I tried a `template class<std::string>` at the end of the namespace but that seems

1. Not working first off, still same exception
2. Not expandable if I have to modify my `.ixx` for everything

Lastly, I'm using C++ 20 with MSVC v143 compiling to a static library. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: It seems there are still some bugs related to modules in current version of MSVC. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/lnk1179-invalid-or-corrupt-file-duplicate-comdat-f/1517475 https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-16104-:-fatal-error-LNK1179:-invali/1497163 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72288809/error-lnk1179-invalid-or-corrupt-file-duplicate-comdat-when-trying-to-build-as

Comment: That's a pity, thanks for the info though